# What causes a jQuery event handler to silently fail? (Weird jQuery Behavior)

Tags: jquery, jquery-click-event

I am receiving unexpected behavior with a jQuery event handler.  It is very similar to the problem discussed in this question: [Why does my jQuery event handler fail when attached to multiple elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2000925/why-does-my-jquery-event-handler-fail-when-attached-to-multiple-elements) .

Basically, a simplified example is, my page calls

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
        $('a.submit').click(function(e){
              e.preventDefault();
              alert(this.href);
        });
   });
```

Assume the markup is:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <a href="url1" class="submit">text1</a>
        <a href="url2" class="submit">text2</a>
        <a href="url3" class="submit">text3</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

All of the links with the submit class except for the last one raise the event.  The last link with `.submit` on the page does not get wired to the event handler.  Replacing `click(fn)` with `live('click',fn)` works.

My problem is I don't understand why the original handler fails.  All the links are rendered at the same time, and I am wrapping my handler-subscription in a `$(document).ready()`, which **should** ensure the DOM is loaded.

I need to figure this out, because I have a more complex situation where the handlers are registered deep inside a minified javascript file, so it would be very helpful if I could understand how to prevent this bug instead of fixing it when it occurs.

One more thing to note is that I am receiving the same weird behavior in Firefox, Chrome and IE.  I am using jQuery1.5.1

Comment: We need to see the html page as well to understand the problem.

Comment: did you mean `$('a .submit')` or `$('a.submit')`

Comment: @Bene, assume it looks like `<html><body><a href="url1" class="submit">text1</a><a href="url2" class="submit">text2</a><a href="url3" class="submit">text3</a></body></html>

Comment: @Naveed, `$('a.submit')`, I updated the question

Comment: @smart I am not able to reproduce your issue: http://jsfiddle.net/simevidas/PhFyn/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering the html you provided:

```
<a href="url1" class="submit">text1</a>
<a href="url2" class="submit">text2</a>
<a href="url3" class="submit">text3</a>
```

and JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('a.submit').click(function(e){
              e.preventDefault();
              alert(this.href);
        });
   });
```

it must work. no doubt about it. However, if your anchor tags `<a>` are being created dynamically, you can't bind the direct click event to those but through live such as

```
$('a.submit').on('click', function(e){
    //magic here
});
```